# Parser Error - Creating EIP20 Tokens

Tags: tokens, ether, eip

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value);
    balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
    balances[_to] += _value;
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value); //solhint-disable-line indent, no-unused-vars
    return true;
}
```

Error Message = ParserError: Expected Toke Semicolon got 'LParen' emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value); //solhint-disable-line indent, no-unused-vars

Answer (score 1):

You're likely using a very outdated version of the compiler. The `emit` keyboard was added in a later release of 0.4.x so would be invalid syntax in older versions. I would suggest using a version in 0.5.x.